# How to redirect part of url to new domain by nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, vhosts

I want to redirect part of old url to new url by nginx.

https://server1.com/app1/app2
to
https://server2.com/app2

https://server1.com/app1/app2/link1
to
https://server2.com/app2/link1

https://server1.com/app1/app2/link2?param1=value1
to
https://server2.com/app2/link2?param1=value1

So part of previous server needs to be redirect to server2.

I tried:
`rewrite ^(/app1/app2.*) https://server2.com$1 permanent;`

Result:
https://server2.com/app1/app2 instead of https://server2.com/app2

How can I manage redirect only url of app2 to new server?

Comment: Hi. Would you try `rewrite ^/app1/app2(.*) https://server2.com/app2$1 permanent;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capturing group takes all the original url and passes it as is to server2. I suggest you to capture only the part after `app2` and redirect this group to `server2.com/app2`.

`rewrite ^/app1/app2(.*) https://server2.com/app2$1 permanent;`